# Computer starts but has no display

Tags: display, troubleshooting

I have my monitor on a table, and the wiring and connections are behind the table. An object (one of my speakers which was on the table) fell on the wires when the machine was on and I was browsing the internet. When I lifted the speaker the screen was on, but the mouse and keyboard were not responding.

I shutdown the PC directly using the power button. After that when I turned on the computer again I found the monitor's display was gone. I could hear the beep and also the welcome sound as my speaker was on. This convinced me that it was booting up as usual. Afterwards I checked all the cables.

In the meantime I had to start and shutdown the PC repeatedly using the power button. After some time I discovered that I could still hear the beep, but the welcome screen sound was gone (my speaker is always on). I realize that at present it is not booting at all, and the display is not showing.

I scan my PC every day using Malwarebytes, and it has no viruses.

Comment: You have symptoms that you know are the direct result of a falling object.  Unless the object was a giant virus, there's no reason to suspect that malware is the problem.  You describe multiple components with problems: display, mouse and keyboard, boot failure.  There's no way people can tell you how to fix the computer from afar.  Even covering all of the diagnostic procedures would be beyond the intended scope of an answer.  Your computer really needs to be examined by a technician to determine everything that is wrong and the options for fixing it.

Comment: The object was one of my speakers which fell on wires behind the table

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the power, disconnect the cables from the computer, open the computer case, and check that all the components are firmly inserted into their slots on the motherboard. Maybe when the speaker fell on the wiring, it pulled the graphics card partway out of its slot on the motherboard, and that is why you aren't getting any signal to the monitor.

Before you restart the computer to test it, check the cables for damage/broken plugs/wiggly pins, and replace the cables with spare cables if you have any identical spare cables on hand. This includes the electrical power extension cord if you are using one. A bad connection on an extension cord can cause a computer to shutdown when the extension cord is wiggled. Afterwards check if the computer is able to boot if the speakers are disconnected.

Comment: At one point of time it was booting as i heard the sound from speakers.  But now it has stopped booting

Comment: I have saw solutions on other forums like disconnecting the power chord and holding on the power button for sometime.   But I can't understand  what power chord is that power chord of cpu or monitor. And by power button they probably meant the cpu button.  Please clarify someone know this kind of technique

Comment: What was written on the forums is not clear to me either, but here is another example. Suppose you are using an extension cord where the ends of the wires are attached to the prongs with screws. If the end of a wire becomes frayed, it can become partially disconnected which causes intermittent power loss when the cable is moved, and eventually causes the cable to fail altogether.